# Variable remains empty after initialization

Tags: apex, java, constructor

Simple Apex (Java actually) question, after I initialized the variable 'a' in a constructor, I tried to access it with a different method but it remains null.

```
Class FirstClass{
    String a;
    public FirstClass (String a){
        this.a =a;
    }

    public void methodWhichIssueOccur() {
        System.debug('a: ' +a); // ---->  a is null
    }
}

@IsTest
Class TestClass{
    @IsTest
    public void testFirstClass(){
        String a = 1;
        FirstClass fc = new FirstClass(a);
        fc.methodWhichIssueOccur();
    }
}
```

Comment: `String a = 1`  will not compile as it's a number and not string. (Hope that's a typo) Try debugging `fc.a` after an instance of `FirstClass` is created.

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor is using the wrong name, try this instead:

```
Class FirstClass{
    String a;
    public FirstClass(String a){
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void methodWhichIssueOccur() {
        if(a == '1') {
            System.debug('a: '+ a); // ---->  a is null
        }
    }
}

@IsTest
Class TestClass{
    @IsTest
    public void testFirstClass(){
        String a = 1;
        FirstClass fc = new FirstClass(a);
        fc.methodWhichIssueOccur();
    }
}
```

Comment: I apologize @vm53 for I made a mistake when posting the question, the constructor name is FirstClass, otherwise it would not let me save it. I edited my post.